# How to automatically nest rows of an Excel spreadsheet using level values?

Tags: excel, grouping, excel-2016

I am attempting to apply grouping to an Excel 2016 spreadsheet so that it can be more easily viewed and interpreted. The data in the spreadsheet is in a format similar to the following:

```
    A  B  C

1   1  x  y

2   1  x  z

3   2  y  y

4   2  x  z

5   2  z  x

6   1  x  y
```

Column A already contains the numbers corresponding to the nesting levels I want in my spreadsheet i.e. rows 3, 4 and 5 are "children" of row 2, so should be grouped together accordingly. The highest level reached in this particular spreadsheet is 5. I do not need to have any further interaction between rows in the spreadsheet, such as calculating subtotals. The spreadsheet is approximately 800 lines and a good solution will be used elsewhere, so doing this manually is not an ideal solution.

How can I get the group function in Excel 2016 to recognise Column A as my grouping and apply the outline accordingly?

Comment: Probably doable using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VBA script has been updated to include more levels of grouping.

It will do what you have requested, grouping rows to the row above, based on the increment number.

How it works is explained as comments within the script, including what could cause a possible failure.

Just to note it will fail if anything other than a number is in column A and also if it does not meet the criteria specified in the example comments.

```
Sub GroupRanges()

' Group levels must start at one and increase by one for each group level
' An error is produced if any levels are skipped
' Excel can only handle eight groups, the script will give a message and end if there are more than eight level groups
' Example: 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 will work
' Example: 1 1 2 2 2 4 4 5 will fail and produce an error, in this case group level 3 was skipped.
' Example: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Will fail, too many levels (more than 8)

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CurRow As Long
Dim StartRng As Integer
Dim EndRng As Integer
Dim GrpLvl As Integer
Dim MaxLvl As Integer

' This can be changed to define a sheet name
Set Sht = ActiveSheet

' find the highest number in the range to set as a group level
MaxLvl = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A"))

' If the Max level is greater than 8, then end the script as grouping cannot go beyond 8 levels
If MaxLvl >= 9 Then
MsgBox "You have " & MaxLvl & " group levels, Excel can only handle up to eight groups. This script will now end."
Exit Sub ' end the script if above eight groups
End If

'Set the Starting Group Level.
GrpLvl = 2

' find the last used row
LastRow = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         
' Change the grouping to the cell above the range
Sht.Outline.SummaryRow = xlAbove

' Remove existing groups to prevent unrequired group levels.
' We now need to suppress error massages when trying to remove group levels that may not exist.
On Error Resume Next ' disable error messages

For x = 1 To 10   ' Repeat 10 times
    Sht.Rows.Ungroup   ' Remove Groups
Next x

On Error GoTo 0 ' Now it is important re-enable error messages

' Start the first loop to go through for each group level
For y = 2 To MaxLvl

    'Reset the variables for each group level pass
    CurRow = 1
    StartRng = 0
    EndRng = 0

    ' Start the inner loop through each row
    For Z = 1 To LastRow

        ' Check value of cell, if value is 1 less than current group level then clear the Start/End Range Values
        If Sht.Range("A" & CurRow) = GrpLvl - 1 Then
            StartRng = 0
            EndRng = 0
        End If

        ' If cell value equals the group level then set Range Values accordingly
        If Sht.Range("A" & CurRow) >= GrpLvl Then
        
            ' Check if row is the first of the range
            If Sht.Range("A" & CurRow - 1) = GrpLvl - 1 Then
                StartRng = CurRow
            End If
        
            ' Check if row is the Last of the range
            If Sht.Range("A" & CurRow + 1) <= 1 Then
                EndRng = CurRow
            End If
        
            ' If both range values are greater than 0 then group the range
            If StartRng > 0 And EndRng > 0 Then
                Sht.Rows(StartRng & ":" & EndRng).Rows.Group
            End If
    
        End If
    
        CurRow = CurRow + 1 ' increase for the next row

    Next Z  ' repeat the inner loop

    ' Increase to the next group Level
    GrpLvl = GrpLvl + 1

Next y ' repeat the first loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou for that. I assume it is fairly intuitive to remove the hardcoded values so that this will work for grouping more nested layers, ie by using a variable called CurrentLevel or similar to track which level is being grouped at a particular line?

Comment: @Stitt I have updated the code as per your comment and as also detailed in your original question.

Comment: As for grouping more than one level, you have to first group the entire range, then do the same for each sub group level. For example first loop will group 12345, next loop will then look for 2345 and create a sub group within the previous group, next loop 345 and create another sub group within the last sub group and so on...